# Android canvas app laggy only for specific mobile/OS version

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, canvas

My app uses HTML5 canvas and uses Cordova to build an .apk file. The game uses canvas greatly (no JS framework).

I have tested my app on 5 android devices. Running on Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 running Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread, the game was unreasonably laggy. It was only laggy when the user was NOT touching the screen, and it seems the OS enables some sort of anti-aliasing when the screen is not being touched - and this seems to cause lag. Is this a known issue with canvas-cordova-android 2.3.6? Is there a way to force disable this anti-aliasing at all times, not just when the user is touching the screen?

The following did not help:

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
CSS image-rendering...
```

Thanks.

Comment: android webview is slow in old devices, so canvas is slow. You can use crosswalk to get a better webview, but it will work on android 4.0+

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I don't want to restrict it to 4.0+ so I may have to just restrict from the OS version which no longer lags, but I don't know what that is, so I need to test on more devices.

Comment: If 2.3.6 lags, the only real version to take care between 2.3.6 and 4.0 is 2.3.7, and it will probably have lag too (there are very few models with android 3, it doesn't appear on the android developer dashboard, so it's below 0,1% https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, now I know which version to restrict. If I can, I will try and test it on 2.3.7. I may actually consider using crosswalk in the future if my apps need higher performance, although it took a lot to get cordova to build my app into apk!
Thanks.